# Not able to get the data in IGO_profiles for Einstein Email recommendations

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations, behavioral-triggers

I am trying to fetch the data in the IGO_Profiles but its not showing whereas IGO_View is getting populated easily and when I am trying to see the payload in the network of our developer tool the payload is also passing correctly.

Is there time period for this to get cover because i can see that out of the blue onw of the dummy record that i was passing was visible but don't know how it got populated there in IGO profiles.

And also when i uploaded the catalog my IGO_PRODUCT and IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS shoulg get populated but its not populated yet.

[image]

All I can capture is IGO_Views.
[image]

Comment: There is a delay, I believe the session has to end, then its a shared queue to write to the DE

Comment: I don't know but just know one record got populated in my IGO_Profiles and its showing me the data and i tested it 3-4 hrs ago.
and the igo_views are getting populated without any delay and i added 4 dummyproduct records in my catalog but started to showing only 2 of them in products and productattributes